# Highchart Heatmap Tooltip get x or key in HeaderFormat

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have date as x axis(even if not date) and need to access the value in header format. But this does not work. 
As per [heatmap header api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.tooltip.headerFormat) they do provide "Available variables are point.key, series.name, series.color and other members from the point and series objects".  But in header format key & others are null. Is that a bug or am i missing something

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prakash4mail/d8svyohm/3/)

```
headerFormat: '1:{point.key} 2:{point.x} 3:{point.y} 4:{point.z} 5:{point.value} 6:{series.name} 7{x} 8:{series.value}'
```

Can some help please get Date at bottom on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules in `headerFormat` are similar to `formatter` function. You can treat first `point` like `this`, so use:

```
  tooltip: {
    ...,
    headerFormat: '2:{point.point.x}'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s8rLngtc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thank you for replying(atleast data is showing & i understood that it is subproperty) but the data is incorrect, the date is of 2020 year but it shows 2013,2014,2015.  @ppotaczek

Comment: `headerFormat: 'pk:{point.key} ppk:{point.point.key} ppx:{point.point.x} ppy:{point.point.y} pz:{point.z} pv:{point.value} ssn:{series.series.name} x:{x} ssx:{series.series.x} ssv:{series.series.value}' ,`
this is what im trying & ppx has bad data

Comment: seems like a bug that should be reported to them :(

Comment: Hi @prakash, No it is not a bug. just use strings with `category` axis type, not numbers. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ju7egpbh/

Comment: Thanks a Ton(really missed that). One last question on this.. so lets say i used strings(which has date) then in tooltip can i reformat it to date ? (does headerFormat support computation) & for it then how can i set the chart x axis to display dates ?

Or is it vice versa.. if x axis is dates then tooltip is bad , & if tooltip is good then axis dateFormat is lost ? @ppotaczek

Comment: Let me also ask, when i hover over a cell, do i get tooltip formatter , seperatley for x axis & y axis ?  @ppotaczek

Comment: What do you mean by reformat date? Generally, you can use `category`(requires point.name as string) or `datetime`(requires point.x as timestamp in millisecond) axis type. Tooltip formatter is not called seperatley for axes.